# How to get rid of tomcat memory leak log entries caused by a sleeping thread

Tags: java, tomcat7

Any idea how I can get rid of the following Tomcat log entries:

```
SEVERE: The web application [/my-app] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-11] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jun 29, 2015 11:14:33 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
```

I'm getting them while shutting down tomcat 7.0.42.

The thread dump looks like this:

```
"Thread-11" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007fedc0bd5000 nid=0x2983 waiting on condition [0x00007fedbacef000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (sleeping)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at com.my.app.Test$WorkerThread.run(Test.java:248)
```

Where the java line 248 is: sleep(1000*60*pollIntervalMinutes);

```
  public void start()
{

    WorkerThread t= new WorkerThread(this);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
}
private class WorkerThread extends Thread
    {
        Controller controller=null;
        int pollIntervalMinutes=0;
        private boolean alive = true;

        public WorkerThread(Controller controller)
        {
            this.controller=controller;
            pollIntervalMinutes=60;
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while(alive)
            {
                try
                {
                    sleep(1000*60*pollIntervalMinutes);
                    controller.createAllProjectsIfNeeded();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    alive = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Is that thread marked as Daemon ?

Comment: Yes it is :  public void start()
    {

        WorkerThread t= new WorkerThread(this);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }

Comment: Can you log catch statement ? I think InteruptedException is never thrown upon exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem seems to be that Tomcat doesn't do anything to try and stop the non-managed threads created by the application.

Looking up the implementation of `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads` which reports the error, JVM threads are skipped from cleanup procedure.

Due to this, i would say that the InterruptedException is never thrown and therefore alive is not set to false, as it would be perhaps expected.

```
 @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void clearReferencesThreads() {
        Thread[] threads = getThreads();

    // Iterate over the set of threads
    for (Thread thread : threads) {
        if (thread != null) {
            ClassLoader ccl = thread.getContextClassLoader();
            if (ccl == this) {
                // Don't warn about this thread
                if (thread == Thread.currentThread()) {
                    continue;
                }

                // JVM controlled threads
                ThreadGroup tg = thread.getThreadGroup();
                if (tg != null &&
                        JVM_THREAD_GROUP_NAMES.contains(tg.getName())) {

                    // HttpClient keep-alive threads
                    if (clearReferencesHttpClientKeepAliveThread &&
                            thread.getName().equals("Keep-Alive-Timer")) {
                        thread.setContextClassLoader(parent);
                        log.debug(sm.getString(
                                "webappClassLoader.checkThreadsHttpClient"));
                    }

                    // Don't warn about remaining JVM controlled threads
                    continue;
                }

                // Skip threads that have already died
                if (!thread.isAlive()) {
                    continue;
                }

                // TimerThread can be stopped safely so treat separately
                if (thread.getClass().getName().equals(
                        "java.util.TimerThread") &&
                        clearReferencesStopTimerThreads) {
                    clearReferencesStopTimerThread(thread);
                    continue;
                }

                if (isRequestThread(thread)) {
                    log.error(sm.getString("webappClassLoader.warnRequestThread",
                            contextName, thread.getName()));
                } else {
                    log.error(sm.getString("webappClassLoader.warnThread",
                            contextName, thread.getName()));
                }

                // Don't try an stop the threads unless explicitly
                // configured to do so
                if (!clearReferencesStopThreads) {
                    continue;
                }

                // If the thread has been started via an executor, try
                // shutting down the executor
                try {
                    Field targetField =
                        thread.getClass().getDeclaredField("target");
                    targetField.setAccessible(true);
                    Object target = targetField.get(thread);

                    if (target != null &&
                            target.getClass().getCanonicalName().equals(
                            "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.Worker")) {
                        Field executorField =
                            target.getClass().getDeclaredField("this$0");
                        executorField.setAccessible(true);
                        Object executor = executorField.get(target);
                        if (executor instanceof ThreadPoolExecutor) {
                            ((ThreadPoolExecutor) executor).shutdownNow();
                        }
                    }
                } catch (SecurityException e) {
                    log.warn(sm.getString(
                            "webappClassLoader.stopThreadFail",
                            thread.getName(), contextName), e);
                } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
                    log.warn(sm.getString(
                            "webappClassLoader.stopThreadFail",
                            thread.getName(), contextName), e);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    log.warn(sm.getString(
                            "webappClassLoader.stopThreadFail",
                            thread.getName(), contextName), e);
                } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                    log.warn(sm.getString(
                            "webappClassLoader.stopThreadFail",
                            thread.getName(), contextName), e);
                }

                // This method is deprecated and for good reason. This is
                // very risky code but is the only option at this point.
                // A *very* good reason for apps to do this clean-up
                // themselves.
                thread.stop();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are three options that i can think of how to avoid this memory leak:

- provide shutdown hook as a thread that knows about your spawned threads and can interrupt them

[How to add shutdown hook](http://java.dzone.com/articles/tomcats-graceful-shutdown)

- do not spawn threads which will spin endlessly in a while loop so they can stop when finished processing
- wrap threads in `ExecutorService` and call `shutdownNow()` upon application shutdown event.

  This can be achieved with Service class annotated with `@WebListener`
  and calling `shutdownNow()` in method:`contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event)`.

**shutdownNow()**

> Attempts to stop all actively executing tasks, halts the processing of waiting tasks, and returns a list of the tasks that were awaiting execution.
>   This method does not wait for actively executing tasks to terminate. Use `awaitTermination` to do that.
>
> There are no guarantees beyond best-effort attempts to stop processing actively executing tasks. For example, typical implementations will cancel via `Thread.interrupt()`, so any task that fails to respond to interrupts may never terminate.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you add a ServletContextListener to your context ([example](http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/)) that communicates with your thread and stops it whenever the context is destroyed.  This way when your app gets unloaded (if you remove the .war or replace it) the thread stops and a new one is started.